# Method "fixation_probabilities" not found in Nashpy library

Tags: python, game-theory

I am trying to obtain the fixation probabilities using Moran process.

I have copied the example from this website (https://nashpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/how-to/obtain-fixation-probabilities.html) but changed it to my matrix and initial population but getting an error come up

```
np.random.seed(0)
repetitions = 2000
initial_population = (10,0)
A = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 1]])
game = nash.Game(A)
probabilities = game.fixation_probabilities(initial_population= (10,0), repetitions = 2000)
probabilities
```

and get this error:

> 'Game' object has no attribute 'fixation_probabilities'

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `nashpy.game.Game` https://nashpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/source/nashpy.html?highlight=Game#nashpy.game.Game

Try with `game = nash.game.Game(A)`

Comment: Hi there, I did this and still get the same error message as well :/

Comment: Ah thank you mkreiger - how do I install that then? sorry very new to this

Answer (score 0):

The method `fixation_probabilities` was added in Nashpy version [0.0.27](https://github.com/drvinceknight/Nashpy/compare/v0.0.26...v0.0.27).

It requires Python 3.8. If you install Nashpy using pip with Python 3.8 you are currently already getting version 0.0.30.

When installing Nashpy using pip with Python 3.7 you only get version 0.0.21, so you should upgrade your Python version to 3.8.